# Printing A Circular Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am doing an Assignment which is about Creating and Printing a Circular Linked List.

Here is my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class node
{

  public:
  int data;
  node *next;
  node() : data(0), next(NULL) {}
};

 class list
{ 
private:
node *first;
node *last;

public:
list() : first(NULL), last(NULL) {}
void add_last(int n)
{
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = new node;
        first->data = n;
        first->next = NULL;
        last = first;
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr = new node;
        last->next = ptr;
        last = ptr;
        last->data = n;
        // cout<<last->data;
    }
}
void add_first(int n)
{
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = new node;
        first->data = n;
        first->next = NULL;
        last = first;
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr = new node;
        ptr->data = n;
        ptr->next = first;
        first = ptr;
        last->next = ptr;
        // cout << last->data;
    }
}
void show()
{
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        cout << "List is Empty.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr = first;
        while (ptr != last)
        {
            cout << ptr->data << " ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        cout << ptr->data << " ";
    }
   }

  };

 int main()
{
 list l;
 l.add_last(1);
 l.add_last(2);
 l.add_last(3);
 l.add_last(4);
 l.add_last(5);
 cout << "Contents of the List:\n";
 l.show();
 l.add_last(11);
 l.add_last(12);
 l.add_last(13);
 l.add_last(14);
 l.add_last(15);
 cout << "\nContents of the List:\n";
 l.show();


 return 0;
 }
```

After Adding 1 2 3 4 5 at last Nodes in list When I print the list
then Output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

After That When I add 11 12 13 14 15 into code
Then The output came is

```
1 2 3 4 5 11 12 13 14 15
```

But I do not want Previous value.
How can I clear Previous List to store New values?

Question May be seems stupid To seniors
But I am a beginner.
So please Humbly Help me.
I will be thankful.

Comment: What does that have to do with printing the list in 1st place?? Just provide a function to clear the list, before adding new values to print.

Comment: `#include <conio.h>`?  `<conio.h>`... Now, that's a header file name I haven't heard in a long time... A long time.

Comment: You are more likely to get help with your clear function if you show the code you have tried. We don't usually just write the code for the missing parts of a program.

Comment: Or just make a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a deletelist method before displaying next added elements as follows:

```
void deleteList()
{

    node* current = first;
    node* next = NULL;
  
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
        next = current->next;
        delete(current);
        current = next;
    }
    first = NULL;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: you need to update last as well